# Triggering a remote job and blocking the actual job while the remote job is being built is not working in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jobs

I have a Jenkins job that triggers a remote parameterized job. I have checked the box next to the `Block until the remote triggered projects finish their builds.`
option. Sometimes it works just fine, but occasionally the first job is not being blocked while the triggered remote job is being built.

Check the following snippet from the log:

> 16:07:00 Blocking local job until remote job completes
>
> 16:07:00 Remote build started!
>
> 16:07:00 Remote build finished with status SUCCESS.

It seems that the remote job finished succesfully in only 1 sec, but actually, the remote job has an approx. 10 minutes long build time and I checked that it is started correctly and was still running when the calling job logged this and went on.

Any idea on what is wrong with the blocking?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what is finishing in 1 sec is just the queuing and firing up of the remote job. Not sure if that's intended or a bug (you might want to ask this on plugin's [JIRA page](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-44264?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20component%20%3D%20parameterized-trigger-plugin)).
It seems though you need to block your parent job yourself until the remote job has actually finished. You might be able to work a polling scheme (say check status every 10 secs or so) based on the env vars that are available when you use the `Block until...` option. Especially `TRIGGERED_BUILD_RESULT_<project name>` (see here https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin)